# What does a compact set look like?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

So for a writing assignment in one of my classes we are asked to discuss and prove some basic results about compact sets in general topological spaces. I like proving these things, but they dont help me understand what a compact( locally compact, paracompact,...) set in a topological space "looks like." That said I'm asking for some examples of compact (locally compact, ...) sets in a variety of topological spaces. I'm also interested in some explanation of what extra "benefits" are brought about by singling out these compact sets. For example the p-adic numbers are locally compact and locally compact things (abelian groups to be precise) are a good setting in which to carry out fourier analyis.

Comment: As you probably know: compact is an important notion because it singles out those spaces which share the basic properties of closed intervals of real numbers:  continuous functions achieve a minimum and maximum, sequences have countable subsequences (here for simplicity of exposition I am ignoring the difference between compactness and sequential compactness), the intersection of a nested sequence of closed subsets is non-empty.  Locally compact spaces are singled out because they share the property of the real numbers (or more generally of Euclidean spaces) that every point has a ...

Comment: ... neighbourhood which is compact, i.e. which has the basic analytic properties of closed intervals.

Answer (score 6):

You could try reading [Terence Tao's notes](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/245b-notes-10-compactness-in-topological-spaces/) on the subject; I found them very informative.

As for examples, here is an example and a non-example which I think are informative.  The example is that, by Tychonoff's theorem, $[0, 1]^I$ is compact for any index set $I$.  The non-example is that the closed unit ball in any infinite-dimensional Banach space, say $\ell_1(\mathbb{Z})$, is *not* compact.

Edit:  Here is another perspective from which to think about compact *Hausdorff* spaces (and LCH spaces).  A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is completely determined by the ring of continuous functions $C(X, \mathbb{R})$; this is a standard exercise which is worked out, for example, [here](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/spectra-of-rings-of-continuous-functions/).  One gets the points of $X$ as the maximal ideals of $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ and the topology as the initial topology making every function in $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ continuous.  Slightly generalized, this is the [commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#Statement_of_the_commutative_Gelfand-Naimark_theorem), and it says that studying commutative C*-algebras with unit is the same thing as studing compact Hausdorff spaces.  Removing the requirement that we have a unit is the same thing as studying locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

So one can write down compact Hausdorff spaces by writing down commutative C*-algebras with unit.  One choice is to take the space $C_b(X, \mathbb{R})$, the space of bounded continuous functions on an arbitrary topological space $X$, with the sup norm.  If $X$ is completely regular Hausdorff, this gives the [Stone-Cech compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Construction_using_C.2A-algebras) of $X$.  (Which is hopeless to think about in general; even for $X = \mathbb{N}$ it's very weird, as the Wikipedia article describes.)

Comment: Wow! What a notes! Thank you, Qiaochu.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understand your question, but here are some elementary examples of compact and non compact spaces. You can find more examples in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness).

1. $[0,1]$ is compact with the subspace topology of the usual, Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Neither $(0,1)$, nor $\mathbb{R}$ are compact with the same topology.
3. A set with a finite number of points $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is always compact. In fact, it is always compact, with no matter which topology.
4. With the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is bounded and closed. Beware: this characterization of compactness is no longer true for arbitrary metric spaces: for instance, with the bounded metric $d(x,y) = \mathrm{min} \left\{ \| x-y\|,1 \right\}$ (which is equivalent to the Euclidean one), every subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, even the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, is bounded. So, if the former characterization was still true with this metric, every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($\mathbb{R}^n$ itself included) would be compact.
5. This countable set $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\ \vert \ n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \left\{ 0\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact (with the usual topology).
6. This countable set $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\ \vert \ n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not compact (with the usual topology).
7. This countable set $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not compact (with the usual topology).
8. With the [finite complement topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_complement_topology), $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. In fact, with this topology on the real line, every subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact. In fact, every topological space with the finite complement topology is compact.
9. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact with the subspace topology of the usual, Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
10. Btw, the empty set is always compact.